# Combine multiple query results sets in one array with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to combine multiple results of a query into one array with php. But i'm find it hard to do. any help?

```
$row = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(school_name) as school_total from schools_tbl");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$school_count = $row->fetchAll();

$row = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(fname) as parents_total from parents_tbl");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$parent_count = $row->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($school_count,$parent_count);
```

Comment: Hm `json_encode([$school_count, $parent_count])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the fetchall() for fetching a single column.. you can use fetchColumn() instead.

```
<?php

$row = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(school_name) as school_total from schools_tbl");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$school_count = $row->fetchColumn();

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(fname) as parents_total from parents_tbl");
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$parent_count = $sql->fetchColumn();

$results = array(
    'school_total' => $school_count,

    'parents_total' => $parent_count
);


echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do something as simple as...

```
echo json_encode(["school" => $school_count,"parent"=>$parent_count]);
```

But as these are arrays of results, you might want to extract the actual count values...

```
echo json_encode(["school" => $school_count[0][0],"parent"=>$parent_count[0][0]]);
```